# oracle select true if not null

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, select-into

I have to select true in a variable when a field is not null, my attempt is this but does not compile, do you have a working solution?

```
        SELECT  CASE blob_data WHEN NULL THEN FALSE ELSE TRUE END
          INTO v_blob_found
          FROM docs dd
         WHERE dd.id=my_id
```

Comment: How did you declare `v_blob_found`?

Comment: SQL, whether it's a `select` or a `select into` statement, does not support Boolean literals. In this situation `TRUE` or `FALSE` will be treated as identifiers, thus `..does not compile` .

Answer (score 4):

You can try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN blob_data IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END
INTO v_blob_found
FROM docs dd
WHERE dd.id=my_id
```

Comment: Can you cast it like SELECT  BOOLEAN(CASE WHEN blob_data IS NULL THEN 'FALSE' ELSE 'TRUE' END) ?

Comment: Well, sorry but no IDEA.